# How to change TitleLabel - Bar Button Item?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem

I have Bar Button Item with Title "Edit" in UITableViewController.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func pushEdit(_ sender: Any) {
    tableView.setEditing(!tableView.isEditing, animated: true)
}
```

I need to change TextLabel from "Edit" to "Done" when the user clicked on "Edit" button.

It seems that setTitle(_:for:) doesn't work.

What is the way to change Title?

Answer (score 2):

.title seems to be what you are looking for.

```
 @IBOutlet var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    
 saveButton.title = "Saved"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by toggling the editing mode and setting the title depending on whether your tableView is being edited

```
@IBAction func pushEdit(_ sender: Any) {
    tableView.isEditing.toggle()
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = tableView.isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit"
}
```